How does one tie together comment, repository_dispatch, and workflows in Github, without using an external store?
I'm looking for a unique identifier in the payloads themselves for Github. My flow is:

Someone types an action as a comment/chatops (/ok-to-test)
An external process is watching the comments, and sees this, and triggers another repository's github action via a repository_dispatch.
The github action runs, and the watcher process (same as in #1) sees the "workflow_run.completed" event, and kicks off another set of functions.
At the end of those functions, I'd like to be able to comment on the ORIGINAL issue.

However, between step 3 and step 4, I lose the ability to pass parameters. I can use client_payload (https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#repository_dispatch) to pass something INTO #3, but I can't pass anything from #3 (a workflow_run) to step #4 (a GHA payload).
Any ideas?
